# JavaScript prototypical inheritance to object methods

Tags: javascript, object, inheritance, frontend, prototype

one quick question.

I know i can make a class and do it with "this", keyword, but can i somehow do it alternatively via prototypical inheritance?

Example:

```
const obj1 = {
    name: "Admin",
    log: () => console.log(obj1.name),
};
```

I make a object with a name and a method that console.logs obj1's name

```
const obj2 = {
    name: "Moderator",
};

obj2.__proto__ = obj1;
```

So i make another object that only has a name, without log method, and i do prototypical inheritance so obj2 now has access to that method even if it's not created with it.

```
obj2.log();

// output: "Admin"
```

How can i bind log method to the object that calls it, so if i use it as obj2 through prototypical inheritance, it will log obj2's name "Moderator"

Comment: Don't use `__proto__`, create an object with `Object.create()` and pass in the prototype to use.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular function instead of an arrow function and access `this.name`.

```js
const obj1 = {
    name: "Admin",
    log() {
      console.log(this.name);
    }
};
const obj2 = {
    name: "Moderator",
};
obj2.__proto__ = obj1;
obj2.log();
```